# Adding element to list change all elements

Tags: python

I have a problem with the following code

```
    my_list = []
    for i in xrange(1, 13):
        my_list.append(MyObject(year=year, month=i))
```

I dont know why when calling append method all elements in the list are replaced by new element. So when loop is finished I have 12 same elements in the list. Please help.

Comment: What does `my_list` look like after the loop? What is your implementation of `MyObject`? There's nothing for us to work with right now.

Comment: How do you define, that all elements are the same? They have same id? Or they just have same year and month? Check, if they have different id (by calling function `id(your_object)`). And if they are, the problem is in `__init__` of your MyObject

Comment: Please include the implementation of MyObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with your MyObject class

Are you storing the year and month as class attributes instead of instance variables?

Comment: Uff, that was a problem thanx a lot :)